# Check for UNIQUE constraint in Node-Postgres

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I have put a UNIQUE constraint on the "email" column of my table and now in my Express API which is using Node-Postgres (pg), I want to make sure than the email that the user puts in when POSTing a student, isn't duplicated.

My question is that how can I show a response like "Email already taken!" in my JSON object when that constraint gets violated?

```
const createStudent = (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, age, dob } = req.body;
  pool.query(insertStudent, [name, email, age, dob], (error, results) => {
     if (error) throw error;
     res.status(201).json({
       message: `Student Created Successfully!`,
       student: results.rows[0],
     });
  });
};
```

Comment: which json object? please add your code to the question.

Comment: I edited the question. I just want to know how to check the UNIQUE constraint in an if/else condition so that if the client puts an email that's already in the database, they get an error or message saying 'Email already taken'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using `async/await` and `try/catch` and providing the error logic in the catch statement.

This now works as expected:

```
const createStudent = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, age, dob} = req.body;

  try {
    const create = await pool.query(insertStudent, [
      name,
      email,
      age,
      dob,
    ]);
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "Student Created Successfully!", user: create.rows[0] });
  } catch (err) {
    // If UNIQUE constraint is violated
    if (err.code == "23505") {
      console.error(err.message);
      const error = new Error("Email Already Exists!");
      error.status = 400;
      next(error);
    } else {
      console.error(err.message);
      const error = new Error("Something Went Wrong!");
      error.status = 500;
      next(error);
    }
  }
};
```

I have used Express Error Handling middleware but the other way work as well.

*Thanks to @boran for his great help!*